# How to secure SQL Server connection to AppHarbor

Tags: sql-server, appharbor

I'm trying to export my database securely to AppHarbor. The data in the database is not encrypted. Here are some concerns I have regarding the security of the transfer.

1. How do I encrypt the transfer? When I try to connect to the server after checking the Encrypt Connection checkbox in SSMS, it does not allow me. "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted."
2. A general question regarding transferring data over the internet. Do I worry about snooping? How is it done, and how great is the threat? The data is not that critical, but since it includes information of others, I prefer to have some level of security.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently offer encrypted connections. If you want, you can get hold of a machine in the US-east AWS location, securely transfer your data there and then move your date from the AWS machine to your AppHarbor SQL Server. AWS guarantees that data transferred between to AWS machines stays on their network.